# GZipped files in VUE , How to load? How are they processed?

Tags: laravel, apache, vue.js, webpack, gzip

So I have gzipped my chunks and app files (css/js) , I have activated the gzip in apache , now the question is , How are those files loaded? The browser checks if it accepts gzip in headers and searches for the file in gzip format? Because I have done it and didn't see a drastic change in page load speed.
Would thank you for explaining this to me (somehow I didn't find a good response on google)

Comment: This is handled by browser transport. Vue is clueless about it. *didn't see a drastic change in page load speed* - this means that bandwidth isn't a bottleneck. Try to load it thorough cellular network and see what happens.

Comment: I was using it on local server , on ip address the gzip files didn't work but on custom domain ( configured through httpd_vhosts ) works , anyways.